# connection error occurring

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

While I'm connecting visual studio 2010 to sql sever 2008, I'm getting an error                                                                                                          A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: Did you try what the message said to do?

Comment: are you connect sql server from nertwork or local

Answer (score 0):

You are able to connect to your sql server through SSMS ?

If yes then it might be issue with your connection string  and else it seems to be issue with credentials or network availability.

More details will be needed in that case.

You can get help in generating connection strings using ".udl" files.